# How do you call or invoke a DLL method from a separate project without declaring it as a reference in the solution explorer?

Tags: c#, .net

If you have an Executable.proj and a ClassLibrary.proj, how do you invoke a method in the ClassLibrary without making it as a reference in the Executable.proj?

Comment: You could use `Reflection` to load the other assembly, find the type and method implementation, and then invoke that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using reflection.
Pseudo code:

```
var asm = Assembly.Load("classlibrary.dll");
var type = asm.GetType("YourType")
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
type.GetMethod("MethodName").Invoke(Instance);
```